# Solidity try catch showing execution reverted of internal tx on Etherscan

Tags: try-catch, solidity, etherscan

I have a function to check if a given token has an Uniswap factory address:

```
address possibleFactoryAddress;
try IUniswapV2Pair(token).factory() returns (address factory) {
    possibleFactoryAddress = factory;
} catch {}
```

Now this code is working perfectly - The `catch` block will be executed if given token does not return an address through its `factory()` function (properly because it does not have that function). However when the tx shows on Etherscan, it has a big yellow exclamation mark on it and a scary warning:

`Although one or more Error Occurred [execution reverted] Contract Execution Completed`

[image]

I know that there is nothing wrong with the code, the tx completed without reverting and all state changes are stored properly, but is this possible for Etherscan to NOT show this big warning? I'm afraid it'd confuse a lot of non-technical people and scare them away.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you link one of the transactions that shows this warning? It's possible that it's consisted of multiple internal transactions - and one of these internals failed.

Comment: That's my point - there are multiple internal transactions, and one failed (an external call) which is caught. In my case the failed transaction does not have any impact on the correctness of the parent transaction. But now that I think about it, Etherscan probably needs to show the warning because someone might attempt to abuse the try-catch, pretend that nothing went wrong and use it to scam people.